# Computational complexity lecture/videos/exercise

Tags: complexity-theory

I have basic background (at the level of Sipser's book),
but am looking to brush it up and get to the more advanced part via self-study.
I have two Computational Complexity books (Arora and Barak and Papadimitriou's).

I am looking for good lectures (online), exercises etc., possibly coursera style, 
for a faster progress with the material.
Any recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: as an old CS prof told me loudly, as a freshman, after class, after asking, _"there are no shortcuts"_ :p ... there are a ton of similar highrated questions on tcs.se incl [top videos](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1198/what-videos-should-everybody-watch) etc

Answer (score 2):

Coursera has materials on Automata by Ullman. You can always "preview" that material. Also for a more complete reference on a first course, may I suggest Gusfield's Lectures (available in iTunesU)

For more advanced treatment, Tim Gowers has few online lectures on [Computational Complexity and Quantum Computation](http://www.sms.cam.ac.uk/collection/545358;jsessionid=53925A3FEE89D7505565619066A413C8)

Also, the AB book is really good. you may want to stick with that.

If you want more advanced materials, looking into the proceedings of STOC or FOCS from the previous years, might be insightful.

Comment: you mentioned AB book to stick with. What is that?

Comment: @SatishPatel, Arora and Barak